# no such column error in android database

Tags: android

when i perfom search method its given me run time error

```
error:- 05-04 14:04:00.227: E/AndroidRuntime(4559): Caused by: 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ww (code 1): , 
while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT faculty, deparment, name, officeNumber, 
phoneNumber, emailAddress, officeHour FROM teacherInfo WHERE name=ww
```

I need to search on teacher name when user enter the name and display all information about this teacher such as name ,faculty,deparment,phone,email,officenumber,officehour

thiss getRecord method in DBAdapter.java

```
public Cursor getRecord(String n1) throws SQLException 
{       
    Cursor mCursor =db.query(true,tableName , new String[] {facultyc,
                deparmentc, namec, officeNumberc,Phonec ,emailAddressc,officeHourc},namec + "=" + n1, null, null, null, null, null);


    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

and this search method in Information.java

```
public void search(){
    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getRecord(n);
    if (c.moveToFirst()){
        t1.setText(c.getString(0));
        t2.setText(c.getString(1));
        t3.setText(c.getString(2));
        t4.setText(c.getString(3));
        t5.setText(c.getString(4));
        t6.setText(c.getString(5));
        t7.setText(c.getString(6));

    }

    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "this Dr not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    db.close();
}
```

this Oncreate method in DBAdapter.java

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table if not exists teacherInfo (teacherNumber INTEGER primary key autoincrement," 
        + "name TEXT not null, faculty TEXT,deparment TEXT,officeNumber INTEGER,officeHour TEXT, emailAddress TEXT,phoneNumber TEXT, location INTEGER );";
            {
                try {
                    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);    
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Cursor mCursor =db.query(true,tableName , new String[] {facultyc,
            deparmentc, namec, officeNumberc,Phonec ,emailAddressc,officeHourc},namec + "= ?", new String[] { n1 }, null, null, null, null);
```

Strings have to be in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you missed the quotes of the string!

Better use the String arguments like that:

```
public Cursor getRecord(String n1) throws SQLException 
{       
    Cursor mCursor =db.query(true,tableName , new String[] {facultyc,
                deparmentc,namec,officeNumberc,Phonec,emailAddressc,officeHourc},
                namec + "= ? ", 
                new String[] {ww}, null, null, null, null);


    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

By that way you avoid any errors and also string special characters are auto escaped!

Answer (score 0):

Your query isn't sanitized. It should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT faculty, deparment, name, officeNumber, 
    phoneNumber, emailAddress, officeHour FROM teacherInfo WHERE name="ww"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are entering wrong query. Change it to ->

```
Cursor mCursor =db.query(true,tableName , new String[] {facultyc,
                deparmentc, namec, officeNumberc,Phonec ,emailAddressc,officeHourc},"name = " + n1, null, null, null, null, null);
```